# Log4net doesn't work after re-deploy SharePoint project

Tags: sharepoint, log4net

I have finished implementation logging for my SharePoint project. All things will be logged by log4net component. The first time when I deloy to production server, it works properly but after doing the changes and re-deploy, it doesn't work any more.

I guess that file is used by another process so i can't have a new log. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can change you logging configuration to log to an other file. However I guess the problem is in you configuration, not that the file is locked. Try you configuration on you dev machine and see if it is not broken. Or check the access rights to the logging folder, does your iis user have access to the folder? Maybe you have changed the app pool user.